# Tornar token do Facebook permanente

Tags: facebook

Fiz uma configuração para integraçao com Facebook e a API está ativa mas quando vai se processada dá o erro.

> Graph returned an error Usuario: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the
>   application to perform this action.

Já fui no developers do Face e ta tudo OK com a configuração e extensão do Token.

O que pode gerar isso?
Há algum jeito de deixar o Token permanente para não perder a integração?
Se troco a senha do facebook o token é desabilitado?

Comment: Por que essa última pergunta? Você trocou a senha?

Comment: Que eu saiba esse token do FB tem prazo de validade, só não sei de quanto tempo, fora as medidas de segurança de desativam o token em certos casos..

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, essa mensagem indica que o usuário não deu a(s) autorizações necessárias a APP. Sugiro que vc delete a APP no facebook e faça login novamente que as permissões serão pedidas novamente.